# Which MS-DOS program implemented the "Methinks it is like a weasel" evolutionary algorithm?

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-software

In the late 1980s I had a set of 3.5″ floppy disks which contained some games like Sleuth, Centipede, Space War, and Sopwith. Also present was a program that I *think* was called "weasel", which was not really a game at all, but a simulation of generating the phrase "[Methinks it is like a weasel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program)". I think it had an orange/yellow/red color scheme.

Is this program available anywhere now?

Comment: I remember playing with this (having read Dawkins' book) and I don't think I wrote my own version of the algorithm. It was probably on a computer magazine cover disk/CD in the UK when Dawkins' book was popular. I've no idea where to find it now.

Comment: country? possible magazine? date range? I remember Sopwith (1984) hitting several early magazine disks. Dawkins program was demonstrated on television in 1987, which may have spurred development of the program you used

Comment: @scruss: UK, late 80s or possibly early 90s. The disks didn’t come from magazines, but were passed to me from a family friend, with hand-written labels. The programs may have been copied off a magazine at some point though.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program), Dawkins wrote the program in BASIC, then rewrote in Pascal, but there was no mention of the platform or the OS.

You may want to browse through the [Rosettacode selection](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm). There is a Pascal version,  but no Basic version specific for MS DOS.

Comment: The "loss" of Dawkins' original AppleSoft BASIC source code has been a matter for much noise in the anti-evolutionary scene (it exists, unfortunately) as it "proves" that Dawkins rigged the code to make it look like evolution is real ... I wish I could make this up.